# Remove items from array when date passed

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

I have an array in my Python Project and I add items to the array with this code:

```
items.append({"date":time.time(), "item":item})
```

I want to remove all the items where the date passed after 10 seconds, I do it with this :

```
items = [item for item in items if item['date'] + 10 <= time.time()]
```

But this code removes all items and not the one that passed 10 seconds, any idea what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to remove items that are existing more than 10 second in the list, for that you should save the one that are less than 10, change your code to check the opposite.

```
items = [item for item in items if item['date'] + 10 > time.time()]
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use the `timedelta` object

```
from datetime import (
  datetime,
  timedelta
)
items.append({"date":datetime.now(), "item":item})
items = [item for item in items if item['date'] + timedelta(seconds=10) > datetime.now()]
```

Comment: This will remove them too. Have you checked your answer ?

Comment: Thanks. I have updated the answer..tested here.https://repl.it/@Geofrocker2/removeitemsfromarraybasedondate

Answer (score 0):

You should be checking if timepoint + 10 seconds is greater than current timepoint, because it means that 10 seconds haven't passed yet

```
items = [item for item in items if item['date'] + 10 > time.time()]
```

I would change the time logic to this to make it more clear:

```
items = [item for item in items if time.time() - item['date'] <= 10]
```

Answer (score 0):

first you should use timedelta.

```
import datetime    

present = datetime.datetime.now()
past = present - datetime.timedelta(seconds=10)
```

then you can easly compare date with < >

for example:

```
for item in items:
    past = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(seconds=2)
    if item['date']<past:
        items.remove(item)
```

Comment: Look at this resource on list comprehension..https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-list-comprehensions-in-python-3

Comment: I know list comprehension. I just gave you a workable exemple.
SO if you use datetime:

items = [item for item in items if item['date'] + datetime.timedelta(seconds=10) <= datetime.datetime.now()]

Answer (score -1):

```
items = [item for item in items if item['date'] + timedelta(seconds=10) >= datetime.now()]
```

it worked for me
and removed all items where the date passed after 10 seconds